# Back pressure with Vertx HttpClient and RxJava

Tags: rx-java, vert.x, rx-java2

I´m having problems to create a "back pressure system". I´m using Vertx HttpClient and RxJava. 
I need to do 6000 request to an external service, and in order to avoid a full in the waitingForQueue, Since this external service cannot process so fast as I send, I put a delay between request/response.

Since this journey is working as batch process no worries if it´s takes a minute.

Here my code

```
return from(subGroups)
        .flatMap(subGroup -> getProductIdsForSubGroup(subGroup))
        .delay(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

This method it´s invoked from a Observable interval that run every 24H passing this list of subgroups(6000)

But after check my logs I cannot see a delay between my request of 50ms

Here 3 of my logs

```
{"@timestamp":"2016-11-30T10:32:48.973+00:00","event":"started","requestHost":"localhost","requestMethod":"GET","requestUri":"/v3/comercial?category=T15EB&clientId=ERROR_NOT_SUPPLIED","requestHash":189630582,"level":"INFO","thread_name":"vert.x-eventloop-thread-5"}
{"@timestamp":"2016-11-30T10:32:48.978+00:00","event":"started","requestHost":"localhost","requestMethod":"GET","requestUri":"/v3/commercial?category=T15EE&clientId=ERROR_NOT_SUPPLIED","requestHash":1296199359,"level":"INFO","thread_name":"vert.x-eventloop-thread-5"}
{"@timestamp":"2016-11-30T10:32:48.981+00:00","event":"started","requestHost":"localhost","requestMethod":"GET","requestUri":"/v3/commercial?category=T15EG&clientId=ERROR_NOT_SUPPLIED","requestHash":228306365,"level":"INFO","thread_name":"vert.x-eventloop-thread-5"}
```

Any idea what I need to do in order to achieve this?.

Regards.

**SOLUTION**

I end up using `concatMap` Please if you have a better solution, let me know

```
return from(subGroups)
        .concatMap(subGroup -> Observable.just(subGroup).delay(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        .flatMap(subGroup -> getProductIdsForSubGroup(subGroup))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that `delay` just delays the emission, so it's essentially wasted time.

If you can query the remote system with let's say up to 10 simultaneous requests / connections, you can use the 2-parameter `flatMap`:

```
return from(subGroups)
    .flatMap(subGroup -> getProductIdsForSubGroup(subGroup), 10);
```

Comment: Brilliant solution, I completely forgot this option!